# How to use "Spark Connection" with databricks to extract data from SQL database and then convert to R dataframe?

Tags: r, scala, azure-sql-database, sparklyr, azure-databricks

I am trying to extract data from an Azure SQL database into an R notebook on Azure Databricks to run an R script on it. Because of the difficulties I have experienced using jdbc and DBI (detailed here: ["No suitable driver" error when using sparklyr::spark_read_jdbc to query Azure SQL database from Azure Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56756844/no-suitable-driver-error-when-using-sparklyrspark-read-jdbc-to-query-azure-s) and here: [How to get SQL database connection compatible with DBI::dbGetQuery function when converting between R script and databricks R notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56701533/how-to-get-sql-database-connection-compatible-with-dbidbgetquery-function-when?noredirect=1#comment99967902_56701533)) I have decided to use the inbuilt spark connector as such (credentials changed for security reasons):

```
%scala

//Connect to database:

import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Config
import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._

// Aquire a DataFrame collection (val collection)

val dave_connection = Config(Map(
  "url"          -> "servername.database.windows.net",
  "databaseName" -> "databasename",
  "dbTable"      -> "myschema.mytable",
  "user"         -> "username",
  "password"     -> "userpassword"
))

val collection = sqlContext.read.sqlDB(dave_connection)
collection.show()
```

This works in the sense that it displays the data, but as someone who doesn't know the first thing about scala or spark I now have no idea how to get it into an R or R-compatible dataframe.

I have tried to see what kind of object "collection" is, but:

```
%scala
getClass(collection)
```

returns only:

```
notebook:1: error: too many arguments for method getClass: ()Class[_ <: $iw]
getClass(collection)
```

And trying to access it using sparklyr implies that it doesn't actually exist, e.g.

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(method="databricks")

sdf_schema(collection)
```

returns:

```
Error in spark_dataframe(x) : object 'collection' not found
```

I feel like this is may well be pretty obvious to anyone who understands scala, but I don't (I come from an analyst rather than computer science background), and I just want to get this data into an R dataframe to perform analyses on it. (I know Databricks is all about parallelisation and scaling, but I'm not performing any parallelised functions on this dataset, the only reason I'm using Databricks is because my work PC doesn't have sufficient memory to run my analyses locally!)

So, does anyone have any ideas on how I can convert this spark object "collection" into an R dataframe?